# Capacitor data sheet

Tags: capacitor, identification, datasheet

Can anyone tell me who the manufacturer is of these capacitors? We are in search of the datasheet to get equivalent, or the same capacitors. [image]

Answer (score 4):

It would appear to be from Electronic Concepts' [5PT series](https://www.ecicaps.com/film-capacitors/5pt-series-film-capacitor/) of film capacitors.

The exact capacitor may no longer be manufactured; it doesn't match anything going by the current marking guide in the [brochure](https://www.ecicaps.com/wp-content/uploads/5PT-full.pdf). The 0950 would appear to be a date code indicating December 2009, so a fairly old model. You may be able to get information on this specific one by contacting the manufacturer, but it's likely that current part number 5PT46L563K would be a functional equivalent (footprint might not be the same, though.).

Comment: Thank you. I will contact the manufacturer. You were a great help.